# Set frames to UIActionSheet

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uiactionsheet

I am working on an iPad application. I have used email and print functionality into it. To show these options I have used UIActionSheet. But the size of UIActionSheet is too large. Can I set frames to UIActionSheet to reduce its size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can at least change the `bounds` of the action sheet, especially the height value. This can at even be done right after the call to `showFromToolbar:` etc. Note that this does not reposition the buttons but only seems to add/remove space from the bottom of the action sheet.

Before changing the layout one has to ask themselves if this is really necessary or if there might be any other option, but I've seen cases where this is necessary (e.g. an UIDatePicker within an UIActionSheet).

Answer (score 0):

```
- (IBAction)openclick:(id)sender
{
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    {


        UIActionSheet *actionsheetttt = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Click me",@"hows You", nil];
        actionsheetttt.tag = 777;
        actionsheetttt.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackOpaque;
        [actionsheetttt showFromRect:CGRectMake(215,319,300,500) inView:self.view animated:YES];
        [actionsheetttt release];
}
    else
    {

    }

}
```